# How to use Disconnect search from the address bar?

Tags: google-search, search-engine

I like https://search.disconnect.me/ as a privacy respecting front-end for Google Search.

I would like to find out how I can evoke Disconnect searches by adding search terms at the end of the URL in the address bar, e.g.: `https://search.disconnect.me/?search=...`. However, a description of the Disconnect search API is nowhere to be found.

Comment: [Same question](http://superuser.com/q/1000139/151741) on Super User.

Comment: More information is required: browser, OS, etc.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos I am asking for a URL API which by definition should be browser-independent.

Comment: Oh, thank you for clarification, though I doubt something like this exists, you might want to email the Disconnect Devs. It might be something they are interested in creating.

Comment: @unor Has been taken care of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already use disconnect in the Chromium omnibox with this setting \https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&search_plus_one=popup, already have disconnect installed.

But I guess this is a browser-independent 'API' call. The search term is in the query parameter. Should be what you're looking for - https://search.disconnect.me/searchTerms/search?location=US&query=bernie+sanders&ses_nojs=Google&create=&location_option=US&lang=&option=&from_homepage=&from_form=true&source=&showIcons=&filterIcons=&js_enabled=1&ses=Google

And a shortened version of that would be https://search.disconnect.me/searchTerms/search?query=bernie+sanders